# Markup Language for Surveys/Questionnaires

Tags: markup, survey

do you know of any markup language for surveys (which separates content from appearance - similarly to LaTeX - so that you can just type in the code and get that displayed in a reliable fashion on-line)? - I found SuML on the web but apparently it's been discontinued for almost a decade :-/

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's this:
http://www.triple-s.org/sssxml1.htm

But it's XML.  However, the page also includes a list of implementors:
http://www.triple-s.org/ssssoft.htm

So maybe it will still work out for you.

Comment: … when it's XML it's better to throw in another language layer on top (similar to HAML).

Comment: I was hoping the implementors would also include a visualization layer on top of the XML to generate something like what the OP asked for.

Comment: So I can't get an actual online questionnaire exported from a document in the triple-s markup language?

Comment: @user1893275: so none of the implementors offered a solution?

Comment: @RonaldBarzell not really :(